# indicator for increase over time

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, case-when

I'm trying to create an indicator for value increase over time within a group. In particular, I'm trying to flag certain `grp` if value ever increases by 50% over time.

I have a raw data that looks like:

```
id    grp     value_dt    value
--------------------------------
1      1      11/20/20     1.4
1      1      11/21/20     0.8
1      1      11/24/20     2.8
1      1      11/25/20     2.5
1      2      11/29/20     1.5
1      2      12/1/20      1.6
2      1      11/21/20     0.8
2      2      11/26/20     0.9
2      3      12/1/20      0.9
2      3      12/3/20      2.8
```

You can see that for `id = 1 and grp = 1`, the value fluctuates as it increases and decreases over time, but because it had increase over time between 11/21/20 and 11/24/20 from 0.8 to 2.8 (greater than 50% increase), I want to flag the whole `grp 1`. I want my output to look like:

```
id    grp     val_ind 
-----------------------
1      1         1
1      2         0 
2      1         0 
2      2         0 
2      3         1
```

I can only think of using min and max (something like below), which doesn't include the 'over the time' factor in...

```
select id, 
grp, 
min(value) as min_grp, 
max(value) as max_grp, 
(max_grp - min_grp) as val_diff, 
case when val_diff >= min_grp * 1.5 then 1 else 0 end as val_ind
```

If anyone can offer their advice, I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by "*over the time' factor*"? Surely two rows (with different `value`s) in the same group are always from different dates.

Comment: @Bergi hi, I mean that the greater value has to happen after smaller value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know if at any point at time there is an increase of 50% , you flag that group. if yes , here is how you can do it,
you need to use cte and window functions :

> ```
> ; WITH cte AS (
> SELECT *
> , CASE WHEN  COALESCE(LEAD(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id, grp ORDER BY value_dt),0)  >= value* 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END val_ind
> FROM  ttt
> )
>
> SELECT 
> id , grp , MAX(val_ind) val_ind
> FROM cte 
> GROUP BY 
> id , grp
> ```
>
> ```
> id | grp | val_ind
> -: | --: | ------:
>  1 |   1 |       1
>  1 |   2 |       0
>  2 |   1 |       0
>  2 |   2 |       0
>  2 |   3 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3d3ea7ee1868ddea7a5620427c0da848)*